# How to retroactively apply an increasing index number to all PFUsers?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Parse's officially suggested method for [querying random objects](https://parse.com/questions/is-it-possible-to-query-for-a-random-object) is to assign an increasing index to all objects in a class, and then using a master index to both keep track of all the objects in the class, as well as using it as a basis to get random numbers. I had not done this initially when initializing `PFUser`s, and would like to do this retroactively and was wondering how I may be able to do so. One of the unique aspects of `PFUser` is that, unless I am logged in as a particular user, I am unable to affect that user's attributes. I was wondering how I could work around this to iterate through all users to assign an increasing index?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a background job in Cloud Code, and use the .each method on a Parse Query with the master key in order to loop through all the users and set a number field.  Something like:

```
Parse.Cloud.job('userMigration', function(request, status) {

  var idx = 1;
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.each(function(obj) {
    obj.set('idx', idx++);
    return obj.save();
  }).then(function() { // update status, finish; });

});
```